# Not able to run steam with Laptop with AMD CPU + NVIDIA GPU + Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, steam, nvidia-geforce

I am getting the following error

```
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6655637
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:2906): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(steam:2906): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  46
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  45
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  47
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210727110139_1.dmp[2969]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210727110139_1.dmp
/home/indranilrnr/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh: line 772:  2906 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

I have already tried to install the 1386 version of nvdia-driver-470 but it kind of takes the nvidia graphics card away and uses llvm pipe but steam runs with the amd gpu, but while I try to get the nvidia gpu back using nvidia-driver-470 with

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470
```

then steam fails again on launch with the above mentioned error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I would be asking steam for help on this. https://help.steampowered.com/en/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried a lot of things and finally have found maybe a compromise in this case.

First step: don't forcibly try to change anything. If you are getting additional drivers by Ubuntu like the normal ones then let it be. If you have just now installed a new gpu then add the latest PPA and drivers (but don't just blindly take any driver on any website ,check the latest tested ones from respective vendors)

Then once you are able to see the drivers installed then reboot. Make sure secure boot is switched off to allow the drivers to be loaded.

Do not try to add weird i386 drivers as most of them are not supported for AMD.

Set the GPU to *on-demand mode* in nvdia x-server settings and then the apu mode and the gpu mode run accordingly. This resolved a lot of my issues with steam. Once done check the video settings to the memory and then reboot and you are ready for the run.

Comment: I don't know about anything else mentioned here, but the i386 packages are required for Steam to run, because (at least some) parts of Steam are 32-bit only.

Comment: but i am not using them ,now in the new fresh run of ubuntu so but if you can confirm which parts are like that or any specific lib then i  can if i have them as like that or the steam is running without it ,i am using ubuntu budgie as of now just for more information